# Trying to connect to an Oracle DB Server using VBA

Tags: excel, database, vba, oracle

As the title states I'm trying to connect to an oracle DB for a vba script.

I was using this article here on how to do it: https://blogs.perficient.com/2015/12/17/connectcompare-databases-excel-macro/

I just have very basic code for connecting and I'm getting an error that says `"[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified"`

My code is:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim dbConnection As ADODB.Connection
    Dim recordSet As ADODB.recordSet
    Set dbConnection = New ADODB.Connection
    Set recordSet = New ADODB.recordSet
    conString = "Driver = {Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};DBQ=####;Uid=<####>;Pwd=<####>;"
    dbConnection.Open (conString)

End Sub
```

One thing I am not sure on is what exactly is DBQ is. I have set DBQ to the name of the database I'm interested in. Not sure if I'm setting that parameter properly.

Thank you and all help is appreciated it.

Comment: what version of oracle? Do you have an Oracle client installed?

Comment: Java(TM) Platform 1.8.0_221
Oracle IDE 19.4.0.354.1759
Microsoft ODBC for Oracle 10.00.17763.01
Hope that helps, or did you mean something else?

Comment: What version of the Oracle database?  12? 19?

Comment: Instead of `DBQ` try using `Server`.  See [this link](https://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle/) for details.

Comment: Hi! sorry about that, I am using Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First question: Did you install an Oracle Client on your machine?

According to your connection string you use the `Microsoft ODBC for Oracle` driver. Connection string must be like this:

```
Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};Server=myServerAddress;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;
```

Note, the connection string is slightly different to the **Oracle** ODBC driver, see
[ODBC Driver Microsoft](https://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-odbc-for-oracle/) vs. [ODBC Driver Oracle](https://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle-in-oraclient11g_home1/)

Second question: Is your Excel 32-bit or 64-bit?

The Oracle Client and the ODBC driver must be the same architecture (i.e. 32-bit vs. 64-bit) as your Excel. The ancient `Microsoft ODBC for Oracle` driver exist only for 32-bit. If your Excel is 64-bit then you have to use the Oracle ODBC driver.

Another note, the default Oracle Instant client does not include the ODBC driver, you have to download and install the "ODBC Package", from [Oracle Instant Client Downloads](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/downloads.html)

Answer (score 0):

There is a comment above to use this format which I believe is correct
"DSN={MyDataSource};UID={MyUserID};PWD={MyPassword};SERVER={MyOracleServer}"

From the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/microsoft/connection-string-format-and-attributes?view=sql-server-ver15) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/microsoft/odbc-driver-for-oracle?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Yo dumb question, but how would I find the "DSN" and "SERVER". I have SQL Developer open with the DB I'm interested in, but not sure where exactly I'd find that info.

Comment: `DSN` is used when you have defined the DSN in your "ODBC Administrator" tool. `SERVER` is used to name the database directly (which you also enter SQL Developer).